# Actualizar relacion manyTomany hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Estoy tratando de actualizar una relacion de muchos a muchos con tabla intermedia en hibernate pero no me deja, es decir lo que quiero hacer es: si tengo las tablas minievento, minievento_ponente, ponente y por ejemplo: minievento(1) minievento_ponente(1,1) ponente(1) y quiero actualizarlo de esta manera: minievento(1) minievento_ponente(1,2) ponente(2)

mis tablas son las siguientes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "minievento")
public class Minievento implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idminievento")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idminievento;
    
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value={"minievento", "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, allowSetters=true)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "minievento")
    private List<MinieventoPonente> minievento_ponente;
```

TABLA PONENTE_MINIEVENTO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "minievento_ponente")
public class MinieventoPonente implements Serializable{
    @EmbeddedId
    private Idsponente idss=new Idsponente();
    
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean eliminar;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date date_eliminar;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"minievento_ponente","hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idponente", updatable = false, insertable = false,
              referencedColumnName = "idponente")
    private Ponente ponente;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"minievento_ponente","hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idminievento", updatable = false, insertable = false,
              referencedColumnName = "idminievento")
    private Minievento minievento;
    @Embeddable
    public static class Idsponente implements Serializable{
      
    
    private Integer idminievento;
    
    
    private Integer idponente;
    
    public Integer getIdminievento() {
        return idminievento;
    }

    public void setIdminievento(Integer idminievento) {
        this.idminievento = idminievento;
    }

    public Integer getIdponente() {
        return idponente;
    }

    public void setIdponente(Integer idponente) {
        this.idponente = idponente;
    }
```

TABLA PONENTES

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ponente")
public class Ponente implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "idponente")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idponente;

@Column(name = "appaterno")
private String appaterno;

@Column(name = "apmaterno")
private String apmaterno;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "estado")
private boolean estado;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={"ponente", "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, allowSetters=true)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ponente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<MinieventoPonente> minievento_ponente;
```

ERROR

> Error creating bean with name 'IEventoRepository' defined in com.eventos.backendeventos.models.repository.IEventoRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.eventos.backendeventos.models.entity.MinieventoPonente column: idponente (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")